# Issue with bringing a value from a SuB-Report into a Main Report

Tags: ms-access

I have a report which has the purpose of providing an Invoice for a company that can show customer details and general Invoice related details. This report has been created based from a form which features a sub-form which is used to record what the customer has bought from the business.

The problem I am currently having is that when trying to implement a total system which is found in the (now) sub-report with the formula `=Sum([frmInvoiceHIre Subform].[Form]![Sub_Total])` it then comes up with a "Enter Parameter Value" for "frmInvoiceHIre Subform.Form!Sub_Total".

One solution that did not work was through basing the report and sub-report from the begining on two queries which were not too difficult to create but the problem still arose in the same fashion. 
I would very much appreciate some help as i've been tried and tested on this problem for hours on end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the full reference of the subform control:

```
=Sum(Forms![mainform]![frmInvoiceHIre Subform].[Form]![Sub_Total])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still getting the Parameter Value error with `Forms!mainform!frmInvoiceHIre Subform.Form!Sub_Total` being the value inside the message box

Comment: Did you change mainform to the name of your actual form name that subform resides? Also be sure to bracket names with spaces.

Comment: Sorry about that lapse with the mainform naming. However when I changed mainform to "rptInvoiceMain" (the name of the parent invoice) it then did the Parameter Value message.

Comment: Are you referencing a form or a report as I see the 'rpt' prefix? They use entirely different reference schemes.

Comment: At the moment I have been working on implementing a totaling system which is based off a Sub-Form into a parent report. I had try to create a completely seperate Sub-Report in order to help fix the problem previously but the concurent problem remained.

Comment: Can you screenshot the setup? Where does the subform reside: on a form or a report? This will dictate to use Reports!... or Forms!...

Comment: I'm not too sure if that is possible anymore I'm afraid... In an effort to fix the problem I deleted the report I was working on along with the sub-report and decided to start afresh. But when trying to create the sub-report within the main report using the wizard, it states that "The link you selected cannot be used".